# методы в односвязном списке

Tags: javascript, структуры-данных

у меня есть заполненный односвязный список

```js
     class Node{
            constructor(value,next=null) {
                this.value=value
                this.next=next
            }
        }
        
    class LinkedList {
        constructor() {
            this.head = null
            this.tail = null
        }
```

Мне необходимо реализовать  метод:

insert(index,value){...} который будет вставлять новый элемент по указанному индексу,а индекс старого элемента и всех последующих будет сдигаться на +1

моя реализация:

```js
    let currentNode = this.head
            let count=0
    
            while(currentNode.next){
                if(count===--index){
                    currentNode.value=value
                    currentNode.next=currentNode.next.next
                    return null
                }
                currentNode=currentNode.next
                count++
            }
```

наш список

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при вызове функции insert(3,9) удаляются элементы с индексом 1 и 2

помогите исправить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если ты работаешь с массивами - тебе поможет метод splice()
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: Если вы добавите непосредственно в вопрос ВАШИ попытки реализации - шансы на нормальный ответ несколько подрастут, сейчас задачка тянет на школьную, и не видно попыток реализации....

Comment: @ksa LinkedList - совсем не массив, и судя по тексту вопроса, автор реализует именно связный список, т.е. релизовать функцию сплайса - ему придется самостоятельно  :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков добавил свою реализацию

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
let currentNode = this.head
while(currentNode.next){
  --index;
  currentNode=currentNode.next
  if(index == 0){  //Возможно тут немного ошибся и тут должен быть не ноль
    let NewNode = new(Node)
    NewNode.value = value
    NewNode.next = currentNode.next
    currentNode.next = NewNode
    return // или break в зависимости от желаемого способа обработки ошибки границ индекса и прочих мелочей :)
  }
  //А так же не обработана ситуация когда индекс находится за пределами списка :) 
}
```

Comment: этот код вставляет после элемента по индексу, подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтоб он вставлял до элемента по индексу

Comment: В коде есть комментарий про ноль, это именно то место которое управляет положением ;) судя по описанному вами поведению там таки должна быть единица :)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы вставить новый узел после трёх имеющихся, надо встать на head и два раза перейти на next. Потом создать новый узел, передав ему тот же next, что и у текущего узла. Потом у текущего назначить next на новый узел